# iTunes Connect - No Beta Entitlement - Phonegap Build

Tags: app-store-connect, phonegap-build, testflight

I want to do beta testing for my app (.ipa) built via PhonegapBuild. I have "No Beta Entitlement" error in iTunes Connect when I upload the .ipa via ApplicationLoader.

I have tried to create new cert & ad hoc provisioning profile and use them, but it still gives the same error.

Need help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the exact command PhonegapBuild uses to `xcodebuild` the project and to `archive` it? We don't use PhonegapBuild but we had an issue similar to what you described a while ago and it was caused by one of the Xcode command line build parameters - I'll look it up if that can help, not sure if you have control over these through PhonegapBuild.

Comment: Not sure about that. But I found the problem, it's caused by the provisioning profile. I changed the ad hoc provisioning profile to apple store provisioning profile and it worked. =)

Comment: For reference in our case the issue was related to the `xcodebuild -exportArchive` call. We changed the `-exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity` parameter to `-exportProvisioningProfile "${profile_name}"` as you can see here: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-xcode-builder/commit/0f1c7ddf1ce149aeb856349139a9cd6a719146fb